# matlab GUI pushbutton call back event handling

Tags: user-interface, matlab, automation, call, back

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I mimic a user click to invoke a callback function for a GUI object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798109/how-can-i-mimic-a-user-click-to-invoke-a-callback-function-for-a-gui-object)

I am trying to write a script in matlab GUI to auto generate the event of a user pushing a button in the GUI. 
For example, I have an update button in the GUI that updates data coming form a server, in the static text fields, but I would like to automate the update process so I can view the latest data without hitting the update button.

Thank You,

Mohsin .

Comment: this one is also relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755672/matlab-gui-automation